# redis configuration to persist and not to persist based on keys simultaneously on same instance

Tags: redis

I am new to Redis, I need to know that is it possible to configure same redis instance to persist data for selected keys and does not persist data for other keys?

any update ?

Comment: NO. You CANNOT. Why you want to only persist parts of keys?

Comment: In my scenario i wanted to use same redis instance and persist data for key e.g. A and not to persist data for another key e.g. B

Comment: Why not persist all keys? Since disk capacity is much larger than memory, it won't be a problem to save all keys. If you insist on saving parts of keys, you have to split the key space to two instances.